# Acquiring a wildcard certificate from Let's Encrypt via `acme-client(1)`

Tags: ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, openbsd, openbsd-httpd

I have a valid certificate from Let's Encrypt that covers both `foo.bar` and `www.foo.bar`. I'd like to add a `wiki.foo.bar` and likely many others in the future, so a wildcard certificate sounds appropriate.

My web server is via `httpd(8)` on OpenBSD 6.8 and, as such, I used `acme-client(1)` to set up the current Let's Encrypt certificate. The issue is, most of the available Let's Encrypt documentation is exclusively for `certbot`, rather than `acme-client(1)` (which is unsurprising).

When I add the `wiki.foo.bar` subdomain to my `/etc/acme-client.conf` configuration and then run `sudo acme-client -vv foo.bar`, it complains with `acme-client: /etc/ssl/foo.bar.crt: domain not listed: wiki.foo.bar`. It also doesn't seem appropriate to perform any sort of revocation either.

Assuming it's even possible, **how do I get a wildcard certificate from Let's Encrypt using `acme-client(1)`?** Otherwise, **how do I add a subdomain to an existing Let's Encrypt certificate?**

Answer (score 2):

Let's Encrypt wildcard certificates require DNS-01 challenge type. OpenBSD `acme-client` only supports http-01 challenge type. If you want a wildcard certificate from Let's Encrypt, one easy way is to use [acme.sh](https://acme.sh)

To support an additional subdomain using `acme-client`, you can just create a new cert using only the subdomain in the same way you created the previous cert, or create a new cert using the domain and all of the subdomains, then delete the previous cert.